# Lookup value using a key and header (vlookup, index number serch)

Tags: google-sheets

Below is the table I'm trying to look up the value.

[image]

If I wanna get the "Date" of No "10", I write 
= vlookup(11, A:D, 4, false)

This works only if I know the index number 4.
How could I get the index number if I only know the header range (1:1) and header (Date), so that below works? 
= vlookup(11, A:D, function_to_get_index_number("Date"), false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is INDEX/MATCH/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(11,A:A,0),MATCH("Date",A1:D1,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or with Vlookup

```
= vlookup(11, A:D, MATCH("Date",A1:D1,0), false)
```